# MVC5 Root element is missing, SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I had a stock mvc5 webapp project running, and then migrated to another database. The new database is an exact mirror.

Before the migration the default login system in asp.net worked fine.
After the migration, I get the following error.

> Root element is missing.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
>
> SourceFile: AccountController.cs

I am new to asp.net and MVC5 so I am not entirely sure why this is happening.
It occurs after visiting the login page, submitting valid credentials and pressing login.

Here is the stack trace, maybe you can spot something I'm missing and point me in the right direction.

```
[XmlException: Root element is missing.]
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +72
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() +5340358
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +163
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) +44
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options) +64
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor.Decompress(Byte[] bytes) +86
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetLastModel(String& migrationId, String& productVersion, String contextKey) +1016
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +54
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +124
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +395
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +11
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +214
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +97
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +39
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +154
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +163
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +472
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +359
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Cheetah2.Controllers.<Login>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Scott\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Cheetah2\Cheetah2\Controllers\AccountController.cs:78
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9721605
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

i assume this has nothing to do with XML but you've created the second DB from scratch then recreated the tables with the same parameters. this may cause missing items or db logics.
if that is the case, try backup your original database (create.bak file) then restore it into the new remote SQL server DB. this is how you insure they are identical.